# What's the use of computed value in Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

We're starting to integrate mobx into our existing project, but I think there still are a few concepts that I don't completely grasp at the moment.

One of them are computed values, what's the actual use of them?

Say I have this store

```
const UserStore = observable({
  user: null,

  setUser: action(user => {
    UserStore.user = user;
  }),

  unsetUser: action(() => {
    UserStore.user = null;
  }),

  isAdmin: computed(() => {
    return UserStore.user && UserStore.admin;
  }),

  isAdmin() {
    return this.user && this.user.admin;
  },
});
```

As you can see, I've included both the computed isAdmin and the 'regular' isAdmin. Both appear to work when used in my project, so I'm not really seeing what the use of computed values are?

Answer (score 0):

Computed values are cached. The [reference](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html) says:

> a computed property won't re-run if none of the data used in the previous computation changed

In your case, a simple logical operation, this won't give you much (and probably be slower). But you can use it for more expensive computations.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Another thing I'm currently struggling with is that `UserStore.isAdmin` as an action, doesn't have it's `this` environment bound to the store, so I'm forced to stop using arrow functions if I want to reference `this.user`. Any solution for that?